# Появляется элемент в правом нижнем углу модального окна при клике на миниатюру

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Друзья**, создал видео слайдер с каруселью внизу. Есть 4 миниатюры под ней, при клике на миниатюру меняются видео. Я не знаю как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на миниатюру 2 появлялась картинка (Learn More) в правом нижнем углу модального окна, а в остальных миниатюрах 1 3 4 выходили картинки (sign up) на том же месте. Помогите это сделать, как это реализовать?  Вот код картинки которая должна высчевиваться

```
<a href="#"><img src="images/cta.png"</a>
```

```js
//JS для поочередного воспроизведения
var labels = document.querySelectorAll('#active label');
for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {

  labels[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var videos = document.querySelectorAll('#slides  video');
    var index = this.getAttribute('for').replace('slide', '');
    var currentVideo = videos[index - 1];

    for (var p = 0; p < videos.length; p++) {
      videos[p].pause();
      videos[p].currentTime = 0;
    }
    currentVideo.play();
  });
}
```

```css
#slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 424px;
  height: 298px;
  left: 140px;
  top: 135px;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
}

#slides {
  width: 424px;
  height: 298px;
}

.inner {
  width: 400%;
}

#slide1:checked~#slides .inner {
  margin-left: 0;
}

#slide2:checked~#slides .inner {
  margin-left: -100%;
}

#slide3:checked~#slides .inner {
  margin-left: -200%;
}

#slide4:checked~#slides .inner {
  margin-left: -300%;
}

#slide5:checked~#slides .inner {
  margin-left: -400%;
}

.page {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

.page video {
  width: 424px;
  height: 298px;
}

.page img {
  width: 424px;
  height: 298px;
}

#overflow {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#slider input {
  display: none;
}

#active label video {
  width: 97px;
  height: 68px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 4px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  top: 4px;
  position: relative;
}

#active label img {
  height: 69px;
  width: 97px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
}

label video:focus {
  border: 2px solid white;
}

#slide1:checked~#active label:nth-child(1),
#slide2:checked~#active label:nth-child(2),
#slide3:checked~#active label:nth-child(3),
#slide4:checked~#active label:nth-child(4) {
  border: 3px solid white;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

#slides .inner {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide1" checked="">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide2">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide3">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide4">
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">

  <div id="slides">
    <div id="overflow">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="page">
          <video src="videos/1.mp4" preload="metadata" autoplay controls></video>
        </div>
        <div class="page">
          <video src="videos/2.mp4" preload="metadata" controls></video>
        </div>
        <div class="page">
          <video src="videos/3.mp4" preload="metadata" controls></video>
        </div>
        <div class="page">
          <video src="videos/1.mp4" preload="metadata" controls></video>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--inner-->
    </div>
    <!--overflow-->
  </div>
  <!--slides-->

  <div id="active">
    <label for="slide1">
         <video src="videos/1.mp4"></video>
        </label>
    <label for="slide2">
         <video src="videos/2.mp4"></video>
        </label>
    <label for="slide3">
         <video src="videos/3.mp4"></video>
        </label>
    <label for="slide4">
         <video src="videos/1.mp4"></video>
        </label>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Только изменил стиль `#slider` мне кажется сейчас то что вам нужно:

```js
//JS для поочередного воспроизведения
var labels = document.querySelectorAll('#active label');
for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {

  labels[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var videos = document.querySelectorAll('#slides  video');
    var index = this.getAttribute('for').replace('slide', '');
    var currentVideo = videos[index - 1];

    for (var p = 0; p < videos.length; p++) {
      videos[p].pause();
      videos[p].currentTime = 0;
    }
    currentVideo.play();
  });
}
```

```css
#slider {
    position: relative;
    width: 424px;
    height: 298px;
    top: 135px;
    margin: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#slides {
  width: 424px;
  height: 298px;
}

.inner {
  width: 400%;
}

#slide1:checked~#slides .inner {
  margin-left: 0;
}

#slide2:checked~#slides .inner {
  margin-left: -100%;
}

#slide3:checked~#slides .inner {
  margin-left: -200%;
}

#slide4:checked~#slides .inner {
  margin-left: -300%;
}

#slide5:checked~#slides .inner {
  margin-left: -400%;
}

.page {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

.page video {
  width: 424px;
  height: 298px;
}

.page img {
  width: 424px;
  height: 298px;
}

#overflow {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#slider input {
  display: none;
}

#active label video {
  width: 97px;
  height: 68px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 4px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  top: 4px;
  position: relative;
}

#active label img {
  height: 69px;
  width: 97px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
}

label video:focus {
  border: 2px solid white;
}

#slide1:checked~#active label:nth-child(1),
#slide2:checked~#active label:nth-child(2),
#slide3:checked~#active label:nth-child(3),
#slide4:checked~#active label:nth-child(4) {
  border: 3px solid white;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

#slides .inner {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide1" checked="">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide2">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide3">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide4">
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">

  <div id="slides">
    <div id="overflow">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="page">
          <video src="videos/1.mp4" preload="metadata" autoplay controls></video>
        </div>
        <div class="page">
          <video src="videos/2.mp4" preload="metadata" controls></video>
        </div>
        <div class="page">
          <video src="videos/3.mp4" preload="metadata" controls></video>
        </div>
        <div class="page">
          <video src="videos/1.mp4" preload="metadata" controls></video>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--inner-->
    </div>
    <!--overflow-->
  </div>
  <!--slides-->

  <div id="active">
    <label for="slide1">
         <video src="videos/1.mp4"></video>
        </label>
    <label for="slide2">
         <video src="videos/2.mp4"></video>
        </label>
    <label for="slide3">
         <video src="videos/3.mp4"></video>
        </label>
    <label for="slide4">
         <video src="videos/1.mp4"></video>
        </label>
  </div>
```

Comment: не нужно менять стиль slider-a так как он стоит именно там где нужно

Comment: ну тогда в чем проблема? конкретно? в приведенном коде он стоял не там где нужно а в право сехал?

Comment: @RamzikGalstyan у меня есть ссылка с картинкой <a href="#"><img src=images/cta.png></a> нужно чтобы она появлялась только тогда когда нажимаешь на вторую миниатюру и появлялась в правом нижнем углу модалки

Comment: @Anton тогда вы не правильно сформировали вопрос и не правильный код дали в вопросе.

Comment: обновил вопрос.